# Printing the output of an external command from a Perl script

Tags: perl

My task is to print information for the user who runs this script in the terminal
The information I need to print is the information I get from writing:

```
parted /dev/... print
```

Is there any file with the same information so I can open and print it with the perl script,
if not I really have no idea how to get a hold of info about which partition that is "boot"
and the size of each partition

Feels like I've been looking all over the internet, maybe I'm just bad at searching for the
right parameters, but I'm lost and any help is appreciated

Comment: Please, don't modify a question, ask another one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could run the command and capture the output

```
open my $cmd, '-|', 'parted', '/dev/...', 'print' || die "Can't run command: $!";

while (<$cmd>) {
    # do something with $_, e.g.
    print;
}

close $cmd || die "Error while closing off command: $!";
```

Answer (score 3):

That's what backticks (`) are for:

```
print `parted /dev/... print`;

print qx(parted /dev/... print);     # Another way to do it

my $output = `parted /dev/... print`;  # Save to variable

...

print $fh $output;   # Use later
```

See [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) for more information.